# Data transfer from/to memory

Tags: digital-logic, memory, microprocessor, bus, processor

Consider an interface (between a memory and a processor, or between a memory and an  ASIC, or similar situations) in which there is a data bus of 8 bit. Suppose I want read a 16 bit data from memory, and that it is stored in two memory's cells of 8 bit.

Which is the part of data that will be transferred before? The 8 MSB (15...8), or the LSB (7...0)?

Comment: For this, you will have to read the datasheet, if its a device with a parrellel bus or even better a DMA it should outline it, this is called the "endianness", however most devices today are little endiannes, so generally the MSB byte gets sent first.

Comment: That depends on what the internal data path is; if it is 8 bits, then any high or low byte meaning is application dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Big-endian is an order in which the "big end" (most significant value
>   in the sequence) is stored first (at the lowest storage address).
>   Little-endian is an order in which the "little end" (least significant
>   value in the sequence) is stored first. For example, in a big-endian
>   computer, the two bytes required for the hexadecimal number 4F52 would
>   be stored as 4F52 in storage (if 4F is stored at storage address 1000,
>   for example, 52 will be at address 1001). In a little-endian system,
>   it would be stored as 524F (52 at address 1000, 4F at 1001).

(Quoted text above from: [techtarget.com - big-endian and little-endian](https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/big-endian-and-little-endian))

The first byte read can be MSB or LSB depending on the endianess. For a **little-endian** system, lower address will have lower byte. Hence, **first 8 bit read will fetch LSB**. (Assuming you read lower address first).

Answer (score 1):

I started answering with endian-ism as well but removed it.

I read the question not in as what order the bytes appear in memory, but which part of data that will be transferred before (where I interpret 'before' as 'first'.)

In that case it depends on the specific CPU. For 16 bits it can write to either, the even or odd address first. You have to study the datasheet.

Where this has significant impact is for example where a FIFO is mapped on several addresses.

Comment: But does it depend only on the CPU, or also on the memory? Do we have to look at both datasheets?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Are you talking about a single 16-bit write to two parallel 8-it memories or two sequential 8 bit write to 8-bit memory. I assumed the last.

Comment: Yes, the last one

Comment: In that case it only depends on the CPU. The CPU has to output two addresses. It can output the highest first or the lowest first. Most designers think incremental so I would do 0,1, or 2,3 (Lowest one first). however there could be a reason where the other way around is faster or less logic.  (I can't think of one at the moment)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much